# Creacion de mensaje request En ChannelFactory

Tags: c#, webservice, wcf

Estoy realizando un método utilizando channelFactory para Envio de Factura -E Dian Via Channel Factory

primera pregunta: han realizado esto?

si es posible realize algo parecido a esto:

```
void SendFacturaFactory()
 {
   BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
   EndpointAddress address = new 
   EndpointAddress("https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co");

  ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel> factory =  new 
  ChannelFactory<IRequestChannel>(binding, address);

  IRequestChannel MychannelFactura = factory.CreateChannel();
  MychannelFactura.Open();
  Message request = Message.CreateMessage(MessageVersion.Soap11, "hello");
  var request = new FacturaDianRequest()
   {
    NIT = "8333111111",
    InvoiceNumber = "FACO2",
    IssueDate = "2018-10-30  ",
    Document = //ruta archivo encrip y en zip,
  }


  Message reply = MychannelFactura.Request(request);
  Console.Out.WriteLine(reply.Headers.Action);
  reply.Close();
  MychannelFactura.Close();
  factory.Close();
 }
```

2do. He trabajado anteriormente en un solo proyecto con ChannelFactory, no se si he construido bien el message request para llevar trazabilidad el envío exitoso y no exitoso de facturas.